# Removing duplicate URLs in Python (non list)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, web-scraping, duplicates

I need help on removing duplicate URLs in my output. I would try to represent it such that I don't have to put everything in a list, if possible. I feel like it can be achieved with some logical statement, just not sure how to make it happen. Using Python 3.6.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.parse import urljoin as join

my_url = 'https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest.html'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

filename = "LinkScraping.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "Web_Links\n"
f.write(headers)

links = page_soup.findAll('a')

for link in links:
    web_links = link.get("href")
    ab_url = join(my_url, web_links)
    print(ab_url)
        if ab_url:
        f.write(str(ab_url) + "\n")

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this without using any data structure of some sort unless you want to write to the file and re-read it over and over again (which is far less preferable than using an in-memory data structure).

Use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

```
.
.
.

urls_set = set()

for link in links:
    web_links = link.get("href")
    ab_url = join(my_url, web_links)
    print(ab_url)
    if ab_url and ab_url not in urls_set:
        f.write(str(ab_url) + "\n")
        urls_set.add(ab_url)
```

Comment: With the same idea, a comprehension seems cleaner IMHO: `urls_set = set(join(my_url, link.get("href") for link in links)` and then you can iterate directly. The order is lost, though.

Comment: @MariusSiuram True, but then you lose the order when writing the set's content to file.

Comment: @DeepSpace Perfect solution. Not sure why I didn't want to use a list/set, but it is exactly what needed to be done. Thank you!